# Modulus of the same number with different prime bases

Tags: modular-arithmetic

My question is how to show solve problems as such:

$$x \ mod \ 3= 0$$
$$x \ mod \ 5= 2$$
$$x \ mod \ 15 = ?$$

By trial and error I found that x can be 27, and hence answer is 12. But how can I solve similar questions without trial and error?

Comment: Use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

There's a formula to know: as a by-product of  a *Bézout's identity* $\;3u+5v=1$, the inverse isomorphism of the canonical isomorphism of the *Chinese remainder theorem*:
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z/15\mathbf Z&\longrightarrow\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z \\
x\bmod 15&\longmapsto (x\bmod 3,x\bmod 5)
\end{align}
is given by:
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z/15\mathbf Z&\longleftarrow\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z \\
3ub+5va\bmod 15&\longleftarrow (a\bmod3,b \bmod 5)
\end{align}

An obvious Bézout's relation is here $\;2\cdot 3-5=1$, so the solution is
$$x\equiv 3\cdot 2\cdot 2-5\cdot 0=12\mod 15.$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $x=5a+2 = 3b$. Then $3|5a+2$ and since we have always $3|3a$ we deduce that $3|(5a+2)-3a = 2(a+1)$. By Euclid lemma we have $3|a+1$ so $a+1=3c$. So
$$ x = 5(3c-1)+2 = 15c-3 \equiv 12 \pmod{15} $$